# Getting this error - type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

Whenever trying to call future data and trying converting to `List`, it returns the error

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Tried type-casting, but no help

On HomePage.dart

```
final getPost = NetworkFile().getPosts();
  List posts;

  void getPostsList() {
    setState(() {
      var res = getPost;
      posts = res as List<dynamic>;
      print(posts);
    });
  }
```

On Network.dart

```
class NetworkFile{

Future<dynamic> getPosts() async {
    var response = await http.get('$kBlogURL' + 'posts?_embed');
    Iterable resBody = await jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return resBody;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are decoding the response and its a `List` of type `dynamic`. There are few method to handle it. You can create a simple PODO class and cast/mapped to it. Or just do like below:

```
List posts = [];

void getPostsList() async {
  final fetchedPosts = await NetworkFile().getPosts();
  setState(() {
    posts = fetchedPosts;
  });
  print(posts);
}
```

[Here is a nice article about PODO](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51).

Comment: It helped! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
final getPost = NetworkFile().getPosts();
Map posts;

void getPostsList() async {
  var res = await getPost;
  setState(() {
    posts = res as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(posts);
  });
}


class NetworkFile {
  Future<dynamic> getPosts() async {
    var response = await http.get('https://onetechstop.net/wp-json/wp/v2');
    var resBody = await jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return resBody;
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198976/discussion-on-answer-by-copsonroad-getting-this-error-type-futuredynamic-i).